# How do I make this perforce swarm error go away in p4v?

Tags: perforce, p4v

```
Could not connect to Swarm. 'Host swarm.mygame.com not found'  - See P4V's log file for more information.
```

I have this above error which prints every time I load up p4v. This is an artifact from a previous project I was working on. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

Run "p4 property -l -n P4.Swarm.URL".

Do you have Swarm?  If not, delete the property P4.Swarm.URL.

If yes, what is your Swarm URL and does it match the output from "p4 property -l P4.Swarm.URL".

If the property is correct (swarm.mygame.com) then your machine can't access that hostname.   Run "nslookup swarm.mygame.com".

Comment: `p4 property -l -n P4.Swarm.URL` worked for me